# What is a better approach to searching a large array for a particular entry multiple times on the same page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to display many icons on the same page but I understand looping through the same array many times each render is too much work and it will reduce performance especially in slower devices. How do you approach this problem?

The `allIconsSet` array is stored and exported in a file and bundled in the app.
The `services` array comes from a server so it can't have React Components but only strings.

```
export const allIconsSet = [
        { id: `live-sports`, icon: <FaTV/> },
        { id: `drinking`, icon: <FaBeer/> },
        { id: `smoking`, icon: <FaCigarette/> },
        { id: `billiard`, icon: <FaBilliard/> },
        // ... 500 more records
]

const services =  [
        { title: `Live Sports`, slug: `live-sports` },
        { title: `Drink`, slug: `drinking` },
        { title: `Smoke`, slug: `smoking` },
        { title: `Billiard`, slug: `billiard` },
        // ... 100 more records
]

function Services()
{
        return (

            <div className="Services">

                    { services.map( service => {

                            const { title, slug } = service

                            const icon = allIconsSet.map( item => {
                                    if ( slug === item.id ) return item.icon
                            });

                            return (

                                <div className="service">
                                        <div className="label">{ title }</div>
                                        <div className="icon">{ icon }</div>
                                </div>

                            )
                    }) }

            </div>

        )
}

export default Services
```

Comment: You could create `allIconsSet` as an object or a `Map` so that the lookup is easier: `allIconsSet = { "drinking": <FaBeer/>, etc }` And then `const icon = allIconsSet[title]`

Comment: are you able to modify the data set? Don't use an array here, just use an object with the id as the key and the icon as the value

Comment: Also, why is each icon a component of its own? Is that normal?

Comment: @adiga is it not? How do you propose I do it instead?

Comment: @adiga Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply transform your icon `Array` into an `Object`. And you'll be able to find an icon like this: `allIconsSet['smoking']`.

```js
const allIconsSet = {
  'live-sports': { icon: <FaTV/> },
  'drinking':    { icon: <FaBeer/> },
  'smoking':     { icon: <FaCigarette/> },
  'billiard':    { icon: <FaBilliard/> },
  // ...
};

const smokingIcon = allIconsSet.smoking;
const liveSportsIcon = allIconSet['live-sports'];
```

If you don't plan to add additional data, you could ditch the `icon` field and directly pass the component as the icon property value, like: `'smoking': <FaCigarette />,`.

NOTE: Icons exists as webfonts that can be used just like any fonts making them easy to use, customizable with CSS and lightweight. Font Awesome does this, you should check it out, it will certainly be less memory/CPU intensive than having one component per icon.

EDIT: Below you'll find an example of webfont usage with [Google Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons).

```css
/* You can replace all of this by putting this in your page <head> tag:
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> */


/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v85/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/* You can then stylized your icon just like any text */
.my-class {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<span class="my-class material-icons">delete</span>
<span class="my-class material-icons">edit</span>
<span class="my-class material-icons">alarm</span>
```

Comment: Objects are definitely the thing I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate on what you proposed in the NOTE section? An example would be helpful.

Comment: @anonym I added a snippet with Google Material Icons, I don't use Font Awesome and the whole "give me your email + create an account so you can access CDN" bothers me, so I did it with material icon, but the process is the same and you'll fine plenty of info on the Font Awesome website.